# Xamarin из текстового файла в Dictonary. Не получает значения

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, словари

Есть текстовый файл с данными формата string, string. Записанный в текстовый файл вида: [2019-12-23 21:00:00Z , 1]
Запятая разделитель.
Перевод данных из файла в коллекцию идет по алгоритму:

```
var assembly = 
IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(MainPage)).Assembly;
        Stream stream = 
assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("App255555.myfile.txt");
        string text = "";
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
        {

            string line = null;

            // while it reads a key
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // add the key and whatever it 
                // can read next as the value
                Dict2020.year2020Dict.Add(line, reader.ReadLine());
            }
            //text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Файл читается. 
Но при проверке значений в коллекции, пишет, что там нет значений.

```
        ListView lv = new ListView();

        lv.ItemsSource = Dict2020.year2020Dict.Keys;

        string hhh = "2019-12-22 21:00:00Z";

        text = Dict2020.year2020Dict[hhh];


        Label label = new Label
        {
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            Text = text,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, 
            typeof(Label))
        };

        Content = label;
```

Буду благодарен любой помощи.

Comment: не знаете как строку разбить по запятой? рано в xamarin лезть ....

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] dictonaryKeyValue = new string[2];
                dictonaryKeyValue = line.Split(',');

 Dict2020.year2020Dict.Add(dictonaryKeyValue[0],dictonaryKeyValue[1]);

            }
```